# Binding from just created class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a class called Channel, that has properties: `channelName`, (more but irrelevant for this question) , and two `List<double>` (`xValues`, `yValues`).

```
public class Channel
    {
        public string channelName;
        public List<double> xValues= new List<double>();
        public List<double> yValues= new List<double>();

    }
```

I also have a class called File, there are properties as: `fileName`, `ObservableCollection<Channel>` `listOfChannels`. File has a method called read(); that creates internally objects of class Channel for reading the data, depending of the data there will be a variable number of channel, and stores in the Lists `xValues` and `yValues` the data.

```
 public class File
  {
         public string fileName{ get; set; }
         public ObservableCollection<Canal> channels{ get; set; }
         public void read() {//stuff}
  }
```

In my program I've created a `ComboBox` that is binded to that data this way:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboFile"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding myListOfChannels}" 
                   DisplayMemberPath="channelName" 
                   SelectedValuePath="channelName" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding selectedChannel}" />
```

Where `myListOfChannels` and `selectedChannel` are defined as:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Canal> myListOfChannels { get; set; }
        public Canal selectedChannel { get; set; }
```

I instantiated them properly later in the code.

When I click a button the file loads and it creates a new object of class `File`. This is my `exampleFile`.

```
 private void openButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            File exampleFile= new File();
            Channel exampleChannel= new Channel();

            exampleFile.fileName= @"C:\Users\Path\myFile.txt"; //I haven't created OpenDialog yet
            exampleFile.read();

            myListOfChannels = new ObservableCollection<Channel>();

            foreach (Channel mychannel in exampleFile.channels)
            {
                myListOfChannels .Add(mychannel);
            }

            selectedChannel = exampleFile.channels[0];
            comboFile.DataContext = this;

        }
```

This is a translation from other language, there can be slight errors in syntax, but it works.
Please, I don't want a complete redesign of this, there are other constrains.
My question is about if it's possible to remove the redundant assignation (`myListOfChannels` and `selectedChannel`, the `foreach` loop, etc) and directly bind the data from my just created `exampleFile`, something like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboFile"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding exampleFile.channels}" 
                       DisplayMemberPath="exampleChannel.channelName" 
                       SelectedValuePath="exampleChannel.channelName" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding selectedChannel}" />
```

I'm extremely newbie here, so if you could actually help me with the writing  that would be great. I've read several tutorials of data-binding but I can't figure out this.

BTW. This may be important: All this code is inside a `UserControl`. In my `MainWindow.xaml` is only a instance of that `UserControl`.

I've tried my best to explain what I want but if something isn't clear just ask it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `Path` on a binding (e.g. `{Binding Something}` is equivalent to `{Binding Path=Something}`) or e.g. `DisplayMemberPath`, it must refer to a property. Not a field (e.g. `public string Something;`), or a local variable (e.g. `void SomeMethod() { string something; }`), but a public property (e.g. `public string Something { get; set; }`).

In your code, `exampleFile` and `exampleChannel` are, as far as I can see, local variables. Also, `exampleChannel` doesn't appear to be used.  You could fix it with something like this:

```
public File ExampleFile { get; set; }

private void openButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExampleFile = new File();

            ExampleFile.fileName= @"C:\Users\Path\myFile.txt"; //I haven't created OpenDialog yet
            ExampleFile.read();

            myListOfChannels = new ObservableCollection<Channel>();

            foreach (Channel mychannel in ExampleFile.channels)
            {
                myListOfChannels.Add(mychannel);
            }

            selectedChannel = ExampleFile.channels[0];
            comboFile.DataContext = this;

        }
```

(as a convention, properties in .NET use PascalCase, so it's `ExampleFile`, not `exampleFile`)

Also of note: if the property can change, and you want the binding to automatically update when that happens, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class(es) you're binding to (in this case, that looks like `File`, `Channel`, and `MainWindow`).

Comment: Thanks! I could remove that foreach loop and bind directly the ExampleFile. It is possible to bind something from another UserControl? For example, I have myControl1 and myControl2. It's possible to check a checkbox in 1 depending on if other chechbox is checked in 2? (A bit offtopic, sorry)